# Books similar to Turtle Geometry

Tags: math, computer-science

Recently I received a copy of "Turtle Geometry: the computer as a medium for exploring mathematics" by Harold Abelson et al. I want to know are there other books that use the same approach (a computational approach) to teach mathematical or physical concepts? I know a couple others about statistics but what about physics or other branches of math?

Comment: See what Khan Academy and others are doing to teach math with computers these days.  Not hard to find.

Comment: Thank you. I know Khan Academy but I asked for books not videos.

Comment: Don't close please, it's a very interesting question.

Comment: Why this post must be closed? It is useful for programmers.

Comment: @gst It's because it's a *poll*-type question. While I agreed that it is very interesting and useful, but it's not really a "question" in the sense of having a "right answer". This is the problem that SO faces, and it needs a uniform policy to keep from being overrun by polls. It's not a bad post. But it is a "bad question". But that's ok! I've got a few closed questions, and nobody teases me about it. I still think they're useful, and keep adding new comments when I find related stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Elementary Functions: An Algorithmic Approach* by Kenneth Iverson teaches you a small subset of the APL language, and then teaches you calculus (in the guise of teaching "Pre-Calculus").

In a way, Bell and Newell's *Computer Structures: Readings and Examples* follows the same paradigm, describing a language and then using it throughout to describe hardware configurations and instruction sets of a wide variety of 70s computers. As does Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*, which describes all of its algorithms in terms of the MMIX (for the old (cheap) editions) assembly language.

Comment: That's all I can think of for now.... wait a moment. *Software Tools* by Kernighan and Plauger, builds a better language (RATFOR) from a crummy language (early FORTRAN) and builds up all the tools for a macro-processor to translate from the high-level to the low-level. ... and that's all I've got for now. I'll add more if I find them. :)

Comment: I found other books that are similar to Turtle Geometry:
1- Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics by Gerald Sussman
2- How to design programs
3- Essentials of programming languages
;-)